# Investors and pools - backtracking

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I've decided to learn deeper the concept of backtracking and I have following task:

Given N investors, M cities, N by M matrix P of investors preferences (P[i, j] = 1 when i-th investor would like the pool to be built in the j-th city; P[i, j] = 0 then he's neutral and when P[i, j] = -1 he's sceptical) and acceptance level L (if for a given choice of places, sum of investors preferences is greater or equal to L then we consider him as convinced). Find maxmimal number of investors that can be convinced and cities in which pools should be built.

I have tried using backtracking but I wonder if it is possible to optimize it more. For now, on each recursion level I keep track of how many people can possibly be convinced. If this number is less or equal to my current maximum then I return (there will be no better answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but with a little trick, you can express the problem as an integer linear program (ILP). Then you can use an integer linear programming solver (for example, GLPK) to find an optimal solution.

Let `s[i]` be 0-1 integer variables (`i` ranging over investors), and `c[j]` 0-1 integer variables ranging over cities and `K` be a large number (`L + the number of investors` will do).

Then, your problem is to minimize `sum(s[i])` such that for each `i`, `sum(P[i, j]*c[j]) + s[i] * K >= L`. The value of `sum(s[i])` in the optimal solution is the number of dissatisfied investors, and `c[j]` indicates whether to build a pool in city `j`.

This formulation of the problem is in a standard form for ILPs, so you're good to go.

Comment: Not exactly but I appreciate your answer!